# Use two services/protocols on port 80

Tags: routing, router, port, port-forwarding

i ran into a problem today. I'am running a home webserver with FTP and everything and want also be able to connect to XBox live.

The problem is (maybe some of you know) that Live uses port 80 (which is totally weird and stupid?) and i can only forward to one of the two devices...

So my question is:

Is it possible to check via an extra server (i got plenty of thin clients laying around) which protocol is running through the port (HTTP should be very obvious right?) and then route it to either the xbox or the webserver.

Explained at this site with a virtual server:
http://community.brocade.com/t5/vADC-Docs/Tunnelling-multiple-protocols-through-the-same-port/ta-p/73802

Beautiful schematic:

(XBOX Live)------|----(Fritz-Box)-----('Demultiplexer'-Server)-------|--(Web-server)
++++++++++++|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|+++++++++++
(user)--------------|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|----------(XBOX)

Hope anybody can help to solve the problem for me and maybe for many others.

**Solution:**

If you use apache add this lines to your conf file  to route every traffic that is not http or your config related to another ip:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName "*"
  ProxyPass / http://ip.from.your.xbox
  ProxyPassReverse / http://ip.from.your.xbox
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: have you considered routing another external port, say 8080, to Live and 80 to your http server?

Comment: @nStensen isnt this impossible? Live tries to connect to the outstanding port 80 and the xbox to the inside port 80 and this cant be changed or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reverse proxy can accomplish what you are looking for. See the answer here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/469879/two-or-more-services-on-same-port-behind-nat?rq=1

You would configure the reverse proxy to accept requests to the DNS name of your web server for example and the send all other port 80 traffic to the xbox.